# External Cookie Validation in Apache HTTP Server

Tags: apache, validation, cookies, proxy

I would like to validate cookies' authenticity using a backend http service, which is hidden behind an Apache HTTP Server - set as reverse proxy. I would also like to avoid scripting (CGI, Perl, Ruby, etc.) and use the Apache configuration only.

This should enable the decoupling of the cookies' validation logic from the reverse proxy itself.

Here are the actors in the flow I would like to implement:

1. Backend main service [Main]
2. Backend Cookie validation service [CookieValidation]
3. Backend reverse proxy [RevProxy]
4. Frontend web browser [Frontend]

Here is the flow I would like to implement:

1. [Frontend] requests a resource from [Main]
2. [RevProxy] intercepts the request

   ```
   ***** Pseudo code *****

   response = send cookie to [CookieValidation] for validation 
   // e.g. *http://CookiValidation.server.com/validate?cookie={...}*

   if (response.status == STATUS_OK) {
       Proxy original request to [Main]
   } else {
       return response
   }
   ```

Will that be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with just Apache "configuration".

If you don't want to write your own Apache module, you'd have to at least write a small script and ivnoke it as a `RewriteMap prg:` script.  It would contact the cookie validation server, and you'd use its output as a test in `RewriteCond` to determine whether to proxy / where to proxy (it wasn't very clear what actions you expected)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: - What I mean by configuration, is the usage of the Apache HTTP server modules' functions, while avoiding scripting as much as possible. I want to avoid scripting as I want less to avoid the maintenance burden as much as possible. - The motivation behind the entire idea, is the ability to separate token validation from the reverse proxy itself, while still controlling the traffic with the reverse proxy. - As I understand from you, this will not be possible without using some sort of an agent (either by code or script)

Comment: This is and old question, but... how would you pass the cookie to the external program? Checking the documentation for rewritemap prg, "for each map function lookup, it expects one argument via STDIN, and should return one new-line terminated response string on STDOUT. If there is no corresponding lookup value, the map program should return the four-character string "NULL" to indicate this." The two ways I see are sending the whole cookie content and letting the program reconstruct it and test it, or storing it and passing the cookie location (this seems slow)